# Python Email send to "Bcc" instead of "To" address

Tags: python, email

I have tried to search many times before I put down this question, but there is no answer for me. 
I'm following the book "Automate Boring Stuff With Python" chapter 16.
I'm currently trying to send email to the receivers as the code format in this book. 
The problem is all email I sent are put the receivers in the "Bcc" instead of "To" address which I want. How can I change from "Bcc" to "To"? Much appreciate if anyone can help me solve this problem.
Sorry for didn't attach the code. Please review.

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("listmail.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
lastCol = sheet.max_column
lastestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value
unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range (2,sheet.max_row+1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r,column=lastCol).value
    if payment != "Paid":
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = email

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login("example@gmail.com", sys.argv[1])

for name, email in unpaidMembers.items():

    body = "Subject: Dues Unpaid\nDear %s, \n\nThis is test"%(name)

    print ("Sending email to %s...." %email)
    sendmailstatus = smtpObj.sendmail("example@gmail.com",email, body)

    if sendmailstatus != {}:
        print ("There was a problem sending email to %s; %s" %(email, sendmailstatus))
smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: We do not have access to the book you referenced. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add the code whatever you tried so that it can be understand where you got wrong.

Comment: the book seemes to be publicly available under: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/

Comment: Are you iterating through all possible recipients or are you handing them as a list to `sendmail(()`?
Please provide a code snippet, since we can only guess your implementation.

Comment: Python documentation: [email examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I forgot to attach the code. This code based on "Automate Boring Stuff With Python" chapter 16, this problem make me headache.

Comment: Anyone can help?